# Get the input values from twig file in Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I am trying to check the username entered to that stored in the database but the value I'm getting from the input in NULL when trying " var_dump($username);", what I'm doing wrong ?

Here is my controller Class

```
 <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Admin;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

   class LoginController extends AbstractController
     {

    /**
      * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
 */
public function connect_admin(Request $request)
{

    $username= $request->query->get('username');

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Admin::class);


    $user =  $repository->findOneBy(['user' => $username]);

    var_dump($username);
    if ($user) {
        $message = "Success";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        return $this->render('site/admin.html.twig');

    }

   else{
    $message = "Try again";


    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
   }


}



   }
```

The form:

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" method="GET" action="LoginController.php">
```

and this what  did in the button href

```
<a class="login100-form-btn" name="button_save" id="button_save" href="{{ path('admin') }}">
                        Login
</a>
```

Comment: The login button is an anchor pointing to a URL. It will always go to `/admin`.

Comment: so how to make it get to the function ?

Comment: What is `$repository->findOneBy()` returning? Please use `var_dump($user)` and paste the output here.

Comment: Furthermore, it looks like the user `root` always exists and, as a result, all requests will be forwarded. I think it would be a better idea to add a field like `is_admin` to the user in the database and check for this.

Comment: @Johannes I have edit it

Comment: You are getting `NULL` because you are outputting `$username` and not `$user` and you are not providing `username` as a query parameter in the URL. Please send the output of `var_dump($user);` and add `?username=<YOUR_USERNAME>` as query parameter.

Comment: it's also NULL for $user, and for the username I want to get it from the <input name="username"> is it correct as I did ?

Comment: You are sending your form data to `YOUR_URL/LoginController.php`, but `LoginController.php` doesn't know that it should execute the `connect_admin()` method. Furthermore, an `a` element does not trigger a form submit except the case if you trigger it via JavaScript manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add an id to the form:

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" id="myForm" method="GET" action="{{ path('admin') }}">
```

Change the login link to:

```
<a class="login100-form-btn" name="button_save" id="button_save" href="javascript:$('#myForm').submit();">Login</a>
```

Now when you click on login link it should submit the form to connect_admin action. Now you can access the submitted values in your controller using

```
$request->query->get('field_name');
```

Comment: it's not working, nothing happen when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

The submit button shoudl be insde the form and better using post method and the action should point on the route not on the controller, so try this:

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" method="POST" action="{{path('admin')}}">

 <input type="text" name="username" />
 <input type="submit">

</form>
```

The controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
 */
public function connect_admin(Request $request)
{

// use request->get not query->get
$username= $request->request->get('username');

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Admin::class);

// find one by username not by user
$user =  $repository->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);

var_dump($username);
if ($user) {
    $message = "Success";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    return $this->render('site/admin.html.twig');

}

else{
$message = "Try again";


echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
```